# How do I fix NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT "error"?

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

I recently upgraded my project to the latest(32) APK version. I also upgraded all dependencies.  A couple of new errors arise. Most of them are easy to solve but what to do with the one below?

[image]

I changed it to one of the "must be's", android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT, and it still gives the same error. What am I missing here?